# Python : How to join multiple video files

Tags: python-2.7

I am relatively new to python so bear with me if this is a question that has already been answered before. I am writing a python script to merge several video files together and I have tried to search the answers online but to no avail. I am wondering if I can write a python script without using ffmpeg just pure python codes for the program. I have tried something like this but it doesn't really works

```
fo=open("outfile","wb")
fo.write(open("infile1").read())
fo.write(open("infile2").read())
fo.close()
```

Comment: Why do you have such an arbitrary restriction?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure, if you can append one video file by the other. Every videofile has a specific format with header, tracks and so on. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream. However, with ffmpeg you can do it like this  :

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:input1.mpg|input2.mpg|input3.mpg" -c copy output.mpg
```

Have a nice day ;)

Comment: from the question: *"I am wondering if I can write a python script _without using ffmpeg_ just pure python codes for the program."*

Comment: @jfs. did you work out how to do this in pure python?

Answer (score 2):

My use case required concatenating a bunch of .mp3 files spread out over 16 folders into one .mp3 per folder. The documentation at [ffmpeg.org](https://ffmpeg.org/) and [ffmpeg-python](https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/) was found to be somewhat lacking or confusing...

I was expecting to be able to create an ffmpeg object and then either pass a list or iterate individual path objects into ffmpeg's input, then run concat on the input objects, and then output to a destination, but `ffmpeg.input(<FILE LIST>).concat(acodec='copy').output(<OUTFILE>).run()` ended up being a massive failball...that is until I came across [@CCfVssZijV2X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2586497/ccfvsszijv2x)'s post containing the concat input formatting which cracked the whole thing for me.

Script below takes base path as input. Assumption is that base path contains folders which contain multiple audio files which are to be concatenated into a single .mp3 per folder as folder name in base path.

If base path contains only one folder, folder batch is sent directly to combine_audio, otherwise the batch list is sent to the multi-processing function which splits each batch over however many cores you have or make available.

While I'm sure the reason for some of my issues with the python wrapper have to do with my ignorance and lack of familiarity with ffmpeg, I hope that this might assist someone or maybe get them started on the correct path for their use case.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from pathlib import Path as p
from os import cpu_count
import ffmpeg

class FFConcat:

    def __init__(self, path, check_files=False):

        self.check_files = check_files
        self.path = p(path)
        self.cores = cpu_count()
        self.batches = []

    def file_check(self):
        '''
        Optional:
        Iterates over folders in path, renames with leading zero for sorting if missing.
        '''
        for folder in sorted(self.path.iterdir()):
            # Folder names were originally "Folder Name - [Disk 1]"
            disk_number = folder.stem.split()[-1].strip(']')
            if len(disk_number) == 1:
                folder.rename('{}/Folder Name - Disk 0{}'.format(self.path, disk_number))
            elif len(disk_number) == 2:
                folder.rename('{}/Folder Name - Disk {}'.format(self.path, disk_number))

    def file_batch(self):
        '''
        Iterates over folders in path creating a list. Converts list into string format
        which is combined with resulting output filename in a dict and added to
        batch list.
        '''
        print('Batching audio files by folder.')
        for folder in sorted(self.path.iterdir()):
            # Use folder names as concat output name for final file.
            outfile = (self.path/'{}.mp3'.format(folder.stem)).as_posix()
            tracks = []
            # Create a list of sorted tracks in folder.
            for track in sorted(folder.iterdir()):
                tracks.append(track.as_posix())
            print('Located {} audio files in \"{}\"'.format(len(tracks), folder.stem))
            # Format file list in string format which ffmpeg will accept via input.
            file_list = '|'.join(_ for _ in tracks)
            # Generate list of dictionaries containing the file list and output filemame
            self.batches.append({
                                'file_list': file_list,
                                'outfile': outfile
                                })

    def combine_audio(self, batch):
        '''
        Input: single dictionary containing a string formatted file list for each folder
        and output filename. Converts list into ffmpeg input concat object. Runs object
        with audio codec copy concatenating files within folder into single file.
        '''
        print('Starting concat for: {}'.format(batch['outfile']))
        tracks = ffmpeg.input('concat:{}'.format(batch['file_list']))
        tracks.output(batch['outfile'], acodec='copy').run()
        print('Completed concat for: {}'.format(batch['outfile']))

    def mp(self, function, iterable):
        '''
        Input: combine_audio function and batch list.
        Sets max workers depending on iterable length and core count.
        '''
        if len(iterable) >= self.cores:
            workers = self.cores
        elif len(iterable) < self.cores:
            workers = len(iterable)
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as p:
            p.map(function, iterable)

    def run(self):

        if self.check_files:
            self.file_check()

        self.file_batch()

        if len(self.batches) == 1:
            print('One batch found. Sending directly to concatenator.')
            self.combine_audio(self.batches[0])
        elif len(self.batches) > 1:
            print('Sending {} batches to multi-processing.'.format(len(self.batches)))
            self.mp(self.combine_audio, self.batches)

concat = FFConcat(path='Base path containing folders with tracks')
concat.run()
```

---

Finally had the need to concat some video, and seeing as one of the comments inquired about just that, here's the quick and dirty I came up with to join two large files together.

```py
from pathlib import Path as p
import ffmpeg

# point basepath to input directory where videos are located. ideally without anything else.
basepath = p('/video_input_directory')

# path iterator to grab input files in basepath, and create a posix filename list.
# you can keep, modify, or drop the suffix filter.
input_files = sorted([
                        _.as_posix() for _ in basepath.iterdir()
                        if _.is_file() and _.suffix == '.mp4'
                        ])

# set output filename
outFile = basepath / 'concated.mp4'

# create file object that will contain files for ffmpeg to concat
input_files_path = basepath / 'input_files.txt'

# iterate over sorted posix files in list, and dump to file in the required format
with input_files_path.open('w') as f:
    for file in input_files:
        f.write('file \'{}\'\n'.format(file))

# this seems to be the proper concat input, with the path containing the list
# of files for ffmpeg to concat, along with the format parameter, and safe, if i
# read the docs correctly, is default/optional
ffInput = ffmpeg.input(input_file_path.as_posix(), format='concat', safe=0)

# output parameters
params =    {
            'c': 'copy'
            }
# input stream -> output stream with output filename and expanded params
ffOutput = ffInput.output(ouFile.as_posix(), **params)

# make ffmpeg quiet
ffOutput = ffOutput.global_args('-loglevel', 'error')

# something, something, run.
ffOutput.run(overwrite_output=True)
```

there's quite a bit of *'s when concatenating video, so definitely check out the [concat section on ffmpeg's site](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat), along with [this ffmpeg concat wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).

Comment: +1 for the mp3 files. I wonder if we mp4 or avi files can be concatenated the same way. Do you have any info regarding videos?

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to concatenate a list of ffmpeg streams? i.e. those already in memory. The case I have is that they're already manipulated and have gone through filters, and now I want to concat them. For now, I'll just go with outputing to temp files.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if I can write a python script without using ffmpeg
>   just pure python

No. you will need an understanding of the codec in order to combine the video content (including the audio tracks) and then package it in to the appropriate container. This is not a trivial task which is why there are libraries to automate it.